# String with variables into a global variable

Tags: bash, shell

My idea is to put this string into a variable then insert into a file, and i made this:

```
line= "this file $file_or_directory has $w lines"
$line >>$file
```

when i execute the error is:

```
line= "this file $file_or_directory has $w lines": command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to fix the assignment by cleaning up the whitespace, then you just need a command to do the actual redirection for you.

```
line="this file $file_or_directory has $w lines"
echo "$line" >> "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat after me:

"Variable assignments must not have spaces around the equals sign."
"Variable assignments must not have spaces around the equals sign."
"Variable assignments must not have spaces around the equals sign."

```
line="this file $file_or_directory has $w lines"
```